# Lazy evaluation to annotations expanding function

Tags: r, dplyr, lazy-evaluation

I wrote a function to expand annotations within groups.

```
function(data, group_col, expand_col){
  data %>%
    dplyr::group_by(!!rlang::ensym(group_col)) %>%
    dplyr::mutate( 
      !!rlang::ensym(expand_col) = dplyr::case_when(
        !is.na(!!rlang::ensym(expand_col)) ~ 
          !!rlang::ensym(expand_col) ,
        any( !is.na(!!rlang::ensym(expand_col))  ) & is.na(!!rlang::ensym(expand_col)) ~ 
          paste(unique(unlist(str_split(na.omit(!!rlang::ensym(expand_col)), " ")) ), collapse = " "),
        TRUE ~ 
          NA_character_  
      )
    ) %>%
    dplyr::ungroup()
}
```

This should take a tibble like this:

```
> t <- structure(list(a = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"), 
    b = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), c = c(NA, NA, NA, "D", "E", 
    NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
> t
# A tibble: 8 x 3
  a         b c    
  <chr> <dbl> <chr>
1 a         1 NA   
2 b         1 NA   
3 c         1 NA   
4 d         1 D    
5 e         2 E    
6 f         2 NA   
7 g         2 NA   
8 h         2 NA
```

And make it became it:

```
> t %>%
+   dplyr::group_by(b) %>%
+   dplyr::mutate( 
+     c = dplyr::case_when(
+       !is.na(c) ~ c ,
+       any( !is.na(c)  ) & is.na(c) ~ 
+         paste(unique(unlist(str_split(na.omit(c), " ")) ), collapse = " "),
+       TRUE ~ 
+         NA_character_  
+     )
+   ) %>%
+   dplyr::ungroup()
# A tibble: 8 x 3
  a         b c    
  <chr> <dbl> <chr>
1 a         1 D    
2 b         1 D    
3 c         1 D    
4 d         1 D    
5 e         2 E    
6 f         2 E    
7 g         2 E    
8 h         2 E
```

Anyone knows whats is the problem with this approach or have any better strategy to assing element in a group by expanding some previously assigned element.

Comment: If you are passing unquoted arguments, an option is curly-curly `{{}}`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this curly-curly, I'll search by immediately, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to use `curly-curly` (`{{...}}`) for doing this in a more compact way

```
f1 <- function(data, group_col, expand_col){
  data %>%
    dplyr::group_by({{group_col}}) %>%
    dplyr::mutate( 
      {{expand_col}} := dplyr::case_when(
        !is.na({{expand_col}}) ~ 
          {{expand_col}} ,
      any( !is.na({{expand_col}})  ) & is.na({{expand_col}}) ~ 
        paste(unique(unlist(str_split(na.omit({{expand_col}}), " ")) ), 
                         collapse = " "),
      TRUE ~ 
        NA_character_  
    ))  %>%
    dplyr::ungroup()
}  



f1(t, b, c)
# A tibble: 8 x 3
#  a         b c    
#  <chr> <dbl> <chr>
#1 a         1 D    
#2 b         1 D    
#3 c         1 D    
#4 d         1 D    
#5 e         2 E    
#6 f         2 E    
#7 g         2 E    
#8 h         2 E
```

Comment: Is possible my dplyr version being different and resulting in an error or I'm missing some library?
I'm having this error: `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: object 'b' not found. 
` with the same example.

Comment: Last errors: `16.
stop(structure(list(message = "Evaluation error: object 'b' not found.", 
    call = mutate_impl(.data, dots), cppstack = NULL), class = c("Rcpp::eval_error", 
"C++Error", "error", "condition"))) 
15.
mutate_impl(.data, dots) 
14.
mutate.tbl_df(.data, !!!mutate_vars) 
13.
mutate(.data, !!!mutate_vars) 
`

Comment: @AurelianoGuedes. Can you check your `rlang` and `dplyr` version.  I used `packageVersion('rlang')
[1] ‘0.4.0’
;packageVersion('dplyr')
[1] ‘0.8.3’`

Comment: I got: `> packageVersion('rlang')
[1] ?0.3.1?
> packageVersion('dplyr')
[1] ?0.7.6?` . I'll update it

Comment: @AurelianoGuedes. the `{{}}` was introduced in `rlang 0.4.0`

Comment: @AurelianoGuedes. Your `dplyr` is also very old.  Many changes happened after that

Comment: I'm having problems to update it. Since I installed R using conda, somehow conda seems that it doesn't know the new versions. Also, I cannot find an update for R itself, my R version is `R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02) -- "Feather Spray"`. Bot, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I have R version `R 3.6`